# Digit extraction function

Tags: python, regex, pandas, function, digits

I have a Pandas series with 16000 rows with some apartments description.
I try to write a function that takes a string and extracts a digit number of rooms.
Some lines doesn't contain any information about rooms.

```
line_example = "Apartment · 121m² · 4 rooms · 2 parking lots"

def rooms_digit_extraction(line):
    # extracts digit number of rooms    
        
        pattern = r"\d{1,2} room?s"
    
    try:
        
        rooms = re.findall(pattern, line) @ returns a list with rooms info if there are any['4 rooms' is case of example]
    
        digit = [int(sub.split(' ')[0]) for sub in rooms] @ extracts the digit from rooms
    
    except TypeError:
        
        pass
    
    return digit

my_pandas_series = my_pandas_series.map(lambda x: rooms_digit_extraction(x))
```

And then next error appears:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'digit' referenced before assignment`

What's wrong with my function? Any help will be really appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Initialize `digit` before `try` block. `digit=None` because if an exception occurs in the `try` block, `digit` won't in scope to return in the `except` block

Comment: `my_pandas_series.str.extract(r'(\d+)\s*rooms?\b')`

Comment: There are multiple issues with this function, where is `stage_1_line defined`?

Comment: @thorntonc you are right, sorry. I changed it. Thank you!

Comment: @bigbounty That works, thank you!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is the best solution for my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
my_pandas_series.str.extract(r'(\d+)\s*rooms?\b')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3vc61A/1).

The `.str.extract` method searches for a regex match in the input string and returns the value captured with a capturing group.

- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `rooms?` - `room` or `rooms`
- `\b` - word boundary.

Comment: Виктор, спасибо большое!